# Use Substring method to count specific character from a string

Tags: c#, string

So I am new to programming and one of my exercises involves using a substring within a loop to count the number of iterations of a specific character with a user's input.

As far as I can tell for the exercise, and what I know in C sharp so far, using a substring in this will only help read the position of a character within the input, and will not count it. I can not make heads or tails of this, and am at a loss.

I want to know how to understand this, and what ways I am missing the point of the exercise.
I need an idea of how to set the substring to read the number of a certain character type from the end-user's input from console.

**This is the original question:**

There is a method called Substring that we can use with a string to look at a portion of a string.

For example, the following code will print the letter a.

```
string input = "abcdef";  
Console.WriteLine(input.Substring(0, 1));
```

**Assignment:**

Given the following input, create a loop that uses the Substring method to count the number of times the letter ‘z’ occurs in a string input by the user.

```
asdfojiaqweb;ounqwrb;ounwqen;zzzn bnaozonza
```

*Edit: So Far I have the code to count the number of times that Z is used, but I don't know how to incorporate a substring into it*

```
int total = 0;  
var letter = new HashSet<char> { 'z' };
Console.WriteLine("Please enter your letters:");

// asdfojiaqweb;ounqwrb;ounwqen;zzzn bnaozonza
string sentence = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
{
    if (letter.Contains(sentence[i]))
    {
        total++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Total number of Z uses is: {0}", total);
// Console.WriteLine(sentence.Substring(0, 1));
```

Comment: Is it a homework? Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have a code in place to count the number of times that Z is used in the input.   I just don't know how to add a substring to it

Comment: Please show what have you done so far.

Comment: just did. I don't know how to add the substring to it. I don't see a reason to in this specific

Comment: Just as a side comment, your code is more efficient than using `Substring`.  `Substring` creates a new string each time you call it, taking up more memory.  Also the `HashSet` is not needed in the code you posted above.  You can instead just use `if (sentence[i] == 'z')`.  Although the `Hashset` can be useful if you need to check for multiple characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use `Substring`, then replace your loop by this

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
{
    if (sentence.Substring(i, 1) == "z")
    {
        total++;
    }
}
```

And if you need to both count uppercase and lowercase `z`, then use following code

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.Length; i++)
{
    if (string.Equals(sentence.Substring(i, 1), "z", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        total++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Does (sentence.Substring(i, 1) == "z") ping the amount of "z"?    How does it count it exactly?  I apologize for my naivety in this. I am trying to understand the substring

Comment: @MossyJoules Yes, it means string at position `i` with length `1`. If it equals to `"z"`, then increment the count.

Comment: Thank you :D I think I get it then. When the string encounters '"z"' it starts at 'i' which is set to 0 the string will then read '1' length of the code, and the increment is activated from there.

Comment: @Niyyoko Yuliawan Again thank you. I apologize for my newbie mistakes, and appreciate the help. This is technically homework, but I am also trying to learn programming as best as I can.  I am learning python on my own, and some things in C Sharp dont' quite make sense to me syntax wise.   Thank you again. I learned something new